# grails 3 war packages and external resources files access

Tags: package, war, grails3

I have built a grails 3 war packages and run it via java -jar myapp.war
the web app is running and I can access it through the default url http://localhost:8080

My app is generating images in an external dir. the layout of the application folder is:

- data/screenshot/${myVarX}/image.png
- myapp.war

Now I'd like to access the PNG files images by clicking on the button in the web app url. In the .gsp file I have this link button.

```
<a href="${resource(dir:''+"data/folder/${myVar}/image.png")}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open glyphicon-white" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="screenshot" data-img="${resource(dir:''+"data/folder/${myVar}/image.png")}"> screenshot</a>
```

How can I access this "static" files from the web page.
Appreciate some experienced help

Comment: '$' {myVar} is not correct, ${myVar} is correct syntax to use groovy variable in gsp

Comment: yes in know @Nitin, but to escape here I enclose the $ character with single quote

Comment: The things is I'd like to access files outside the grails war package. I know how to do it in the web app while running the grails run-app but not with the standalone war package

Comment: You can get that value in javascript variable as var myVar = "${myVar}"; and use that javascript variable in href.

Comment: or you can render the complete path from action as a model to that gsp

Comment: @NitinDhomse, thanks for you reply. Well the things is that war runs on its own with "java -jar myapp.war" . and in the same directory where I have the myapp.war , I have the "data/screenshot/${myVarX}/image.png" that got created dynamically by action controller of the my app.war webapp. Basically it is trying to access files on FileSystem outside of the webapp context. Any idea?

Comment: As a debugging strategy I will recommend you to try with a hard coded href image path first, see that, are you getting image displayed, after that try to construct the dynamic path from the code (put println or console.log) then compare both path.

Comment: I have already tried hardcoding the path but the thing is I'm not sure whether when using a grails war package, it's possible to access a file system directory outside of the war package ?

Comment: The question is more: is it possible to access files in a directory outside of the packaged war file ?

Comment: Yes, you can access directories / files outside of a war file.

Comment: What is the issue / error / exception?  if your server and files are resources of two different user  then you need to provide the access, it is very strait forward thing to read files from your system

Comment: Let me explain: I have packaged a grails app in a war file with embedded tomcat using "grails package" cmd. This generates a "myapp.war" file that I execute with "java -jar my app.war". I open a the web browser "http://localhost:8080/myapp". In the web page, I click on a button, that execute from a controller, an action which executes a "action.jar" file on the file System, that "action.jar" generates "*.png" files in another file system directory. Now I navigate to the web page and click another button that should display "*.png" files in the browser. But the war doesn't have access to it.

Comment: Which OS you have?

Comment: provide access of that file system to user ( which have this tomcat)